# Vertically center without using table-cell and with an unknown height

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center a block of text that has an unknown height and table-cell will also not work for it (width needs to be 100% of the parents). The section I am trying to center is the headerText p class. I've included the html/css down below. Any help would be great thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="headerContent">                      
            <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
            <a href="#windSection" id="scrolldown">Scroll</a>

            <h1 class="title">Title</h1>

            <p class="headerText">
                TEST GOES HERE. THIS IS THE TEXT I AM TRYING TO CENTER. IT HAS NO SET HEIGHT.>
            </p>

            <div class="green select">

                <a class="button" href="links/calculator.html">Discover</a>

            </div>

            <img class="people" src="images/people.png" />

            <p class= "noElechouse"></p>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerContent {
    position:relative;
    width:55%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;

}

.title {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    color:white;
    font-size:90px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}

.headerText {
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:27px;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you open to JavaScript centering it for you?

Comment: Yea I'm fine with javascript although I do prefer a css version @KevinPei

Comment: Oh sorry @JoshC it's the headerText class. I'll add that into my question thanks!

Comment: @kduan You're trying to center it between the title and the 'discover' link? If so, you would likely need to remove the `padding-bottom`/`margin` from the `h1` element. There is no reason `table-cell` wouldn't work in this instance though. What has an unknown height? Is it `headerText` or something else?

Comment: @JoshC oh wow... I can't believe I forgot about that... Thanks!

Comment: @JoshC table cell does center it however for some reason reduces the width of .headerText and pushes the title to the left

Comment: @kduan Give it a width of `100%` after making it `table-cell`. That should work.

Comment: @kduan Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/R9q4k/

Comment: @kduan Should I put that as an answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you don't need to use JavaScript for this.

First remove `padding-bottom:15px` from the `.title` element and set the `margin` value to `0`. Then give the `.headerText` element a margin of `0 auto 10px`; which sets `margin-top` to `0`, and `margin-bottom` to `10px`. Given that the element has a width of `90%`, `auto` is used to center is horizontally. The vertical alignment isn't an issue anymore because both the vertically adjacent elements have a seperating margin of `10px`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9q4k/)

```
.title {
    font-family:'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:90px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.headerText {
    font-family:'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:18px;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto 10px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use the following:

```
.headerText {
    font-family:'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:18px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 10px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the height, you would have to either estimate it's size using percentages, i.e.,

```
.headerText { width:90%; height:50%; margin:25% 5%; }
```

or use javascript to center it vertically

```
#headerText { width:90%; top:50%; margin:0 5%; } //CSS

var eh = document.getElementByID('headerText'); //change from class to ID
eh.margin.top = -(eh/2);
```

or all jQuery

```
ht = $('.headerText');
elH = ht.height();
wH = $(window).height();

marginTop = (wH/2)-(elH/2);
ht.css('margin-top',-marginTop);
```